# Upload file and some other fields to different servers

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, amazon-s3

I have a HTML form with a file upload field and a text input field (eg. a PDF upload field and its description). I want to store the PDF file on AWS S3, but save the description in MySQL on  my server. If the form is

```
<form action="http://my.server.com/upload_file/">...</form>
```

the PDF file will go to my server, and my server then store it on S3. But what I want is, the file go to S3 directly. I know I can set the form to

```
<form action="https://s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post">...</form>
```

to directly upload file to S3, but after that, I can't get the file description from my server. Please help me to find out the best method to do it.

Thank you very much for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do an ajax-request and get the description from the textfield and send it to you server.

1.handle the onsubmit-event

2.get the input

3.send ajax to server